# PHP: how to use system() without return

Tags: php, system

I would like to launch a firefox instance with PHP using `system("firefox &");` but the `system()` function doesn't return until I have closed firefox. The only option I found is to have an already runing instance of firefox before.
So, how do I launch program with PHP without waiting for them to close ?

PS : `exec()` and `passthru()` seems to do the same.

thanks

Comment: `shell_exec()` and maybe add `firefox >> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to pipe all output into nothing.

Comment: working now, thanks a lot !